# How to solve/workaround a bug in Windows System Look and Feel

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, look-and-feel

In Windows LaF JButtons have a Border around which cannot be configured by `setBorder()`. Because of this border JButtons don't fit into the Look And Feel.

As you could see in this screenshot
[image: http://tijamocobs.no-ip.biz/border_jbutton.png]
there is a small border around JButtons in Windows 8 Look And Feel.

This border is the background of the JButton. It's inside the border, which is the reason why I cannot use `setBorder()` and `setBorderPainted(false)` to configure it. `setMargin()` doesn't solve the problem, too. Since in the real program I just want to use an icon as description, without any text, i could use `setContentAreaFilled(false)` but that's just a workaround for the button and it doesn't help the user to see the icon being a button. `setOpaque(false)` doesn't increase the size of the Button, too.
There seems to be no Key for `UIManager.put(_key_,_value)` which can solve this problem.

Another workaround might be changing the design of the frame, that all elements, except buttons, get an additional border. But that seems to be strange and I think it might cause problems with other Look And Feels.

For me, the only solution seems to be modifying the related paint-methods, but that is no solution since I want to use the System Look And Feel. It seems to be a bug in the Look and Feel!?

Is there any other possibility, I don't know about (I didn't mention above)?

(Just to be clear: my problem shall not delete the focus-border! I want the icon to fill its complete space, without the little background-colored space around, which is maybe just 1 pixel thick)

I just spent some time to countercheck the idea of a bug. I made a simple WPF-Project with Visual Studio 2013. I wrote the following XAML-Code and the bug got proven: in a normal Windows Application, a button with 30 height fills the complete place with the button-drawing - there is no such border!

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"/>
        <Button Content="Button" Height="30" Width="30" Margin="200,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

anyway: is there a solution to solve this bug? is this a bug in your opinion?

**short Example**

```
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    public TestFrame(){
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            JButton btn = new JButton(".");
            add(btn);
        }
        pack();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        TestFrame tiss = new TestFrame();
        tiss.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

**Example Code (long version):**

This example shows a little bit the real design of the frames. A difference might be that the buttons in the real application only contain an icon without any text.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

public TestFrame(){
    JPanel muh = new JPanel();
    muh.setLayout(new BoxLayout(muh, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        Container c = new JPanel();
        c.setLayout(new BoxLayout(c, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        Box bx = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        final String[] tmp = {"anything1","anything2"};
        JComboBox<String> cmbbx = new JComboBox<String>(tmp);
        cmbbx.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(80,20));
        bx.add(cmbbx);
        JButton btn = new JButton(".");
//      not working:
//      btn.setBorder(null);
//      btn.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        btn.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(cmbbx.getMinimumSize().height,cmbbx.getMinimumSize().height));
        btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30,30));
        btn.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(30,30));
        bx.add(btn);
        c.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE,30));
        c.add(new JLabel("Just anything"));
        c.add(bx);
        muh.add(c);
    }
    add(muh,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    pack();
}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException,     IllegalAccessException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        TestFrame tiss = new TestFrame();
        tiss.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: did you try: `btn.setBorder(new EmptyBorder())` or even `btn.setBorder(null)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes I tried `btn.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder())` and `btn.setBorder(null)`, thanks for the Hint (sorry, forgot the notify ;) )

Answer (score 0):

just add this line

```
btn.setFocusPainted(false);
```

Comment: I Just added an Edit which says that i don't mean the focus, thanks anyways :)

Comment: Since i don't have the required 10 Reputation for doing this, sorry no. I Just uploaded it to my personnal Webspace. Unfortunately i cannot guarantee that the Image will be there forever :(.
Here's a Link:
http://tijamocobs.no-ip.biz/border_jbutton.png